# Align the beginning of second line of text to the first one

Tags: html, css, inline

I show on my website posts in list items like in the following image:

[image]

But as you can see above, the text on the second line it's starting from the beginning of the row and I would like to start it as the first one:

[image]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<li class="showPosts">
    <span class="greekCross">✚</span>
    <h5>Hvordan ser jeg statistik omkring besøgende?</h5>
</li>
```

And the CSS:

```
.showPosts {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.greekCross {
    color: #00BFF3;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.showPosts > h5 {
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

I've tried to add paddings and margins to the cross symbol or to wrap the heading in some sort of box hoping that the text will line up but with no success. I tried as well other solutions from the Internet but I wasn't able to fix the issue so any guidance is more than welcomed. I hope I've explained myself clear enough.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/xcr0a7x9/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following CSS:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/oxps2huk/)

```
.showPosts {
    cursor: pointer;
    display:table;
}
.showPosts .greekCross,.showPosts h5{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

By making each child a distinct cell, you maintain the vertical alignment on resize.

Answer (score 3):

You can float the "+" left and give some left margin to the `H5` :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/rc9ryLbw/)**

*Note : Use `em` units for the width of the `<span>` and the `left-margin` so they adapt to the font-size.*

*CSS :*

```
.showPosts {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:200px;
}
.greekCross {
    color: #00BFF3;
    font-size: 15px;
    width:1.5em;
    float:left;
}
.showPosts > h5 {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response, i've already fix the issue but I've learn a trick from your answer aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a negative text-indent? For example:

```
.showPosts > h5 {
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-indent:-25px;
    margin-left: 20px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/xcr0a7x9/1/) with the answer u asked. Hope its correct

```
.showPosts {
    cursor: pointer;
    display:table;
}
.greekCross {
    color: #00BFF3;
    font-size: 15px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.showPosts > h5 {
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following style

```
.showPosts {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.greekCross {
    color: #00BFF3;
    font-size: 15px;
    float:left;
}
.showPosts > h5 {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Ref:  http://jsfiddle.net/dsn0gp4q/