# How can I align the beginning second line of wrapped text with the beginning of the first line?

Tags: html, css

So I am aware this question has been asked already on here but I have been looking over those answers for a while and still can't figure out how to work in the solution (I'm a novice to HTML/CSS). For clarification, it is the same question being asked here: [Align the beginning of second line of text to the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309682/align-the-beginning-of-second-line-of-text-to-the-first-one).

So, [Here is what my output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiBMz.png) and [here is the html behind it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMhA0.png)

What I am trying to do is make it so that, in the 1rst paragraph of my output, the "t" in "to" is vertically aligned directly below the "C" in "Contributed," while in the 2nd paragraph the "t" in "traffic" is directly below the "P" in "Part," you get the idea.

I know this seems like a basic question but if anyone could show me how to fix it I would really appreciate it. Have spent hours on the internet trying to figure it out and nothing has worked.

Comment: You can try adding `text-indent: 0 !important;` to your div's style.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments, the text-indent:0  !important; fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just, create a `class` for the `div`, and set `width`, `padding` and `margin`.

The content will always be aligned to the left, and every first word, will be aligned too.

**HTML**

```
<div class="text">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, ratione. Rem architecto excepturi aspernatur non, quos soluta esse magni quisquam quidem animi officia quae voluptatem molestiae debitis neque quaerat natus.</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem voluptatem explicabo rerum dignissimos magnam reiciendis nostrum at consectetur odit. Sunt voluptates fugiat nulla, neque veritatis alias aut dolore, eos unde.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.text {
    font-size:12px;
    padding:5px;
    width: 500px; 
}
.text > div {
    line-height:1.4;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/191af3x1/2/)